# Angular 4 main page (localhost:4200) and routing index of my website

Tags: angular

my problem is:

in my apps index.html there is:

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

and i have a couple components like:
 1. Header
 2. About
3. Offer
4. Projects
5. Contact
6.Footer

My app.component.html contains:

```
<app-header></app-header>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

On HeaderComponent there are routerLinks to each component (About, Offer, Projects, Contact)

I wish, on localhost:4200/, display AboutComponent content, and replace it with other when routerLink is clicked. Now my localhost:4200/ is empty, and About page is on localhost:4200/about.

Is it possible to put "index page" on localhost:4200/ and hide it when subpage is triggered (e.g. localhost:4200/contact) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with the following `Routes` array ([docs](https://angular.io/guide/router)).

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
  // your other routes
];
```

This needs to be imported in the `AppModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your routing module (app-routing.module.ts), you can either redirect the root directory to about

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/about', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

or you can set the root path to use AboutComponent

```
{ path: '', component: AboutComponent },
```

so your full routing file would look something like this for the first option

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
    import { OfferComponent } from './offer.component';
    import { ProjectsComponent } from './projects.component';
    import { ContactComponent } from './contact.component';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/about', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
        { path: 'offer', component: OfferComponent },
        { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent },
        { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
    ];

    @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {

    }
```

or if you go with the section option, it'd look something like this...

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
    import { OfferComponent } from './offer.component';
    import { ProjectsComponent } from './projects.component';
    import { ContactComponent } from './contact.component';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: '', component: AboutComponent },
        { path: 'offer', component: OfferComponent },
        { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent },
        { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
    ];

    @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {

    }
```